# How to increase PHPStorm 9 heap size?

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

I have installed the EAP of PHPStorm 9 and I am trying to increase my allocated heap size without any luck.

I am on Mac OS X Yosemite and I am following the instructions on this page:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/tuning-phpstorm.html

> The file /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions should be copied to
>
> ~/Library/Preferences/WebIdeXX/idea.vmoptions

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Didn't have any issues with doing the exact same thing for PHPStorm 8.

Answer (score 4):

**What you have to do**

- Go to your PhpStorm installation directory
- open the .vmoptions file (learn more on [JetBrains help](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/tuning-phpstorm.html))
- increase the value of the Xmx-Setting to a reasonable amount
- restart PhpStorm and enjoy your bigger heap

**Two things are important**

- Heap size < total amount of RAM
- Keep your Java installation updated

---

Here are some links for a little more background on what to change and why:

- Check the [JetBrains help site](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/tuning-phpstorm.html) for detailed instructions on what files to change
- Learn more about the [configuration options of JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html) (the info also applies to JDK and JRE)
- Check out my vmoptions on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/e0DKn3f9) as an example
- Read about [why increasing heap size is a good idea](http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/)
- If you're interested in getting even better performance with PhpStorm [read this post](http://www.qualitycodeblog.de/performance-tweaks-phpstorm/)

Note: this settings also apply to WebStorm and [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html).

Answer (score 2):

Solved, in case anyone needs the solution:

I followed the instructions from the "Tuning PHPStorm" page however this time I copied phpstorm.vmoptions into my Library/Preferences folder, working like a charm.

Comment: Clarification: ~/Library/Preferences/WebIdeXX/phpstorm.vmoptions is the file it will check. If you are not sure which .vmoptions file it is using, in phpStorm, in the Help menu choose "Show Log in Finder". In the log file search for vmOptionsFile. When it is working correctly, there is a comma separated list of options files. Mine looks like -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/phpstorm.vmoptions,/Users/stevep/Library/Preferences/WebIde90/phpstorm.vmoptions